# Button inside frame removes all content MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

When i add a button to the grid inside a frame, it becomes all gray

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:YtMADapp.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewModel:MainPageViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Class="YtMADapp.View.MainPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:YtMADapp.Model"
             x:Name="Page">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:BaseViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <Grid
      ColumnSpacing="5"
      RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CollectionView 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    Grid.RowSpan="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Videos}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:VideoDTO">
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Frame HeightRequest="125" Style="{StaticResource CardView}">
                                <Grid Padding="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <Grid Padding="10" ColumnSpacing="20">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="Título:" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <Label Text="Id:" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            <Label Text="Autor:" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                            <Label Text="Url:" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                            <Label Text="Qualidades:" Grid.Column="4"/>
                                            

                                    </Grid>
                                        <Grid Padding="8" ColumnSpacing="20">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Author}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Url}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                        <Button Text="Download" Grid.Column="4" Background="Red" Command="{Binding BindingContext.DownloadVideoCommand, Source={x:Reference Page}}"/>

                                    </Grid>
                                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <SearchBar Grid.Row="1" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="3" Margin="8" x:Name="Pesquisa" Text="{Binding Pesquisa}" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchVideoCommand}"></SearchBar>
            <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       Grid.RowSpan="3"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

        </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[Frames without any info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty6JO.png)

When i remove the red button

[Work as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTjrt.png)

Already tried using entry and label and works alright, it just happens with buttons.
Editing while the app is open works, but after restarting it becomes all gray again.
The labels are not invisible or with the same color of the background, they are in the correct position but without any content.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Why is the button on a different row than the labels?

Comment: Tried to change rows to see if something would change, it does not.

Comment: @Glibandor When I add the red buttons inside the frame, the content can show as expected, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zigT.png), please help show your `ViewModel` code.